Restoring Solr backup with different number of shards
I was wondering whether you can restore a collection from a backup with different number of shards. In other words, is there any way to restore a collection with a different number of shards to the backup?
If I have a backup with 6 shards, is there any way to restored it with 3 shards?
Cheers and thank you in advance.
